# I am trying to read a wave file using librosa and I am getting the following error. why am i getting this error and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, audio

Code used -- (rate,sig) = wav.read("audio.wav")
Error -- ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 7339993 into shape (2)

Comment: The `.read()` method returns two elements, whereof the first is a long array of values. If you want to store them in two objects, don't use brackets. Otherwise, it tries to force the whole array (first return) to the 2-tuple you specify. Just write `rate,sig = wav.read("audio.wav") `. So, the outputs are stored in two variables. `rate` should then contain an array of length 7339993

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: Please add your full code and updated code with Martin's comment and the full stack trace to the question.

Comment: I solved it by extracting audio from video using ffmpeg and then reading the wav file